# Powershell Stored Procedure Parameters not being sent

Tags: sql, powershell, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in a PowerShell (version 4) script that logs the results of a job

```
function Log-Build($lastExitCode, $result, $taskId) {
    $date = Get-Date
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $myResult = $result -join "<br/>`r`n" |Out-String
    $cmd.Connection = $connection;

    $cmd.CommandText = "LSBuild_LogAndMailResult";

    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task_ID",[string]$taskId);
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Result",[string]$myResult);
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Deployment_Status",[int]$lastExitCode);

    $connection.Open()
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
    $connection.Close()
}
```

However, when I run it, I always get the following error response:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Procedure or function 'LSBuild_LogAndMailResult' expects parameter '@Deployment_Status', 
>   which was not supplied.

I checked in the terminal window in Powershell ISE to make sure the parameter was there ( $cmd.Parameters["@Deployment_Status"].value;) and it is definitely being added. Not sure why it's not getting passed to the database

Comment: `$LASTEXITCODE` is an automatic variable, rename the `$lastExitCode` parameter in the function to something else

Comment: I just tried removing $lastExitCode and adding a hard-coded integer (0) as the sql param, but still received the same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set command type as stored procedure

```
$cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
```

Comment: Thanks that was it -- I couldn't find documentation on that anywhere